# Change element CSS by hovering another

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I change element CSS by hovering an another element in CSS?

We use this:

```
.example .example2 li:hover .element
```

If we have:

```
<div class='example'><div class='example2'><li></li></div></div>
<div class='element'></div>
```

But if we have:

```
<div class='example'><div class='example2'><li></li></div></div>
<div class='exemple2'><div class='element'></div></div>
```

we could not use  `.example .example2 li:hover .exemple2 .element`

Is there any method to put the parent element `.exemple2` to select his child `.element` in the hover?

Comment: Whilst this post is very old, just be cautious of using hover as hover doesn't really work on mobile devices :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.exemple:hover > .exemple2 .element
```

Comment: it does not work for me i went to style the .element

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the adjacent sibling combinator.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/adjacent-sibling/

Comment: it does not work for the hover

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `+` [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), like:

```
.exemple:hover + .exemple2 .element{
    color: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/cz6L7ctu/)

Comment: i was thinking that is the same
 .example . example1 li:hover + .example2 .element this doesn't work
 li:hover +  .example2 .element this work

Comment: @Imgonzalves this is my demo
https://jsfiddle.net/cz6L7ctu/1/

Comment: Oh I see, then it's not possible with CSS3, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). And please delete the comments to keep it clean.